# How to enable touch screen emulation in Chrome devtools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, multi-touch, gestures, emulation

TL;DR - I've enabled touch screen emulation and it's not working. HELP.

I'm using google-chrome ver 44 on OSX and have the "Emulate touch screen" option checked in my devtools emulation tab. When holding down shift and scrolling I am expecting the pinch/stretch gestures we're all familiar with.

Yet, pinch/stretch gestures are not applied in web pages (e.g. google maps) when I hold down shift and scroll up/down (two fingers scroll on my macbook).

More info: 
when the mouse pointer is over the device emulator, I press shift and the round 'touch' cursor turns into a 'resize' cursor. It's just that the actual scrolling has no effect.

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong?
[image: devtools enable emulation checked]
[image: chrome version]